# Double spend attempts examples on testnet?

Tags: testnet, doublespend

Where can I find some double spend attempts examples on testnet? Can anyone refer me some TXIDs with double spends on testnet?

EDIT: I need some example in which an outpoint was intended to be used in two different transactions, like this one:

https://blockchain.info/tx/6900440e3bf9d7177ef69b8ca8bb620cb439d9261ce54b3df564f6778547003c

but on the testnet.

Comment: What does you mean? Bitcoins cannot be double spent.

Comment: I assume you mean a situation where two conflicting transactions appeared in close succession?

Comment: A double spend wouldn't persist itself in the chain, as the longest chain will cause that double spend to be invalid.

Comment: @makerofthings7 right. I want to mark the surviving transaction as a 'double spend' attempt, just to alert the user

Comment: There are multiple temporary chains.  In that case you will need to monitor each chain and derive your use case in your app...  I don't think that the temporary chains are kept permanently and are purged over time.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid transactions are not kept as part of the blockchain; they are, after all, invalid. Your best bet might be to listen to the chatter on the network (you'd require a custom-written client for this, I would imagine).

Comment: Connecting a program to the SOCKS5 proxy will be also sufficient.